# role of chi2 in SLAM back-end optimization

Tags: slam, theory

All-most all SLAM back-end implementation compute chi2 estimates. Chi2 computation is usually used to compute the best-fitness score of model to the data.
How it is related to optimization framework for SLAM?

Rgds
Nitin

Comment: Check this out http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws09/robotics2/pdfs/rob2-11-dataassociation.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically, the [Chi-Square Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution)(or Chi2, $\chi^2$, or equivalently $\chi^2_1$)  is used to model the probability of the absolute value of the deviation of the measurement from it's expected value. This calculation is vital to tackle the [measurement origin uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_uncertainty) problem. It can also be used to determine the "correctness" of a multi-hypothesis estimate using a similar idea, but I won't touch on that specifically.

Note that the $\chi^2_k$ distribution has $k$ degrees of freedom. Why $\chi^2_k$? Any time you assume [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (e.g., $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$) measurement noise, you will encounter the $\chi^2_1$ distribution because the [two-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) squared of a $n$-dimensional vector of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ variables is equivalent to a $\chi_{n}^2$ pdf. [see: [Applications of Chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Applications)].

In SLAM it is commonly used to model the probability of a certain landmark providing a certain measurement.

Comment: Can you point to some literature how it gets related to landmark observations?

Comment: Yes, but honestly just googling "data association chi-square" or "data association mahalanobis distance" will provide a ton of references. It is standard practice. For a nice introduction, see Bar-Shalom's "Estimation with Applications to Tracking and Navigation"